# How to inscribe two red circles as shown in the figure.

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: TwoInscribedRedCircles]

Create an equilateral triangle. Add circles at the corners of the triangle with a radius equal to half the side of the triangle. At the centre of the triangle create a big circle which touches tangentially all the three circles. Now I need to add a red circles which touches tangentially to the small inscribed circle, big circle and the line as shown in the diagram.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: They are already inscribed. What does your post really ask? It's not clear.

Comment: You can be inspired by this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362007/305862

Comment: @Andrei OP has the three big black circles. He is looking for a geometrical construction with which he can inscribe the two red small circles as shown in the diagram. Do you know such a construction?

Comment: Create an Isosceles triangle. Add circles at the corners of the triangle with a radius equal to half the side of the triangle. At the centre of the triangle create a big circle which touches tangentially all the three circles. Now I need to add a red circles which touches tangentially to the small inscribed circle, big circle and the line as shown in the diagram.

Comment: I think you mean [_equilateral_ triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle).

Answer (score 2):

The first part of our answer shows how to calculate the radius of the smallest inscribed circles shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$  using trigonometry. In the second part, we describe a geometric construction to achieve the same result graphically using compass and straight-edge. The formulae derived in both parts give the exact size of the radius of this pair of twin circles.

[image: TwinInscribedCircles]

$\bf{\underline{\text{Part 1}}}$

In order to derive an expression for the radius of sought circles, we had to analyse the configuration described by OP to find out whether it is possible to inscribe other pairs of twin circles meeting the mentioned requirements elsewhere inside the base circle.

As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, we found two more such pairs of twin circles. The radii of these inscribed circles are larger than that of the circles OP seeks. The largest of the three pairs happens to be two of the three inscribed circles mentioned by OP in his problem statement.

[image: TwoInscribedCircles]

Please pay your attention to $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, in which $O$ denotes the center of the given base circle with the radius $R$. The points $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ are the centers of the three given circles having the radius $a$. According to OP’s description, these three points are also the vertices of an equilateral triangle, which has $O$ as its centroid.  Let us assume that the circles we are looking for have radii $b$ and their centers located at $B_1$ and $B_2$. Either of these two circles must touch the base circle internally, while being externally tangential to one of the given inscribed circles and the vertical line through $O$. Our aim is to express $b$ in terms of $a$ or $R$. Furthermore, let $\measuredangle B_2OE=\theta$.

Since $O$ is the centroid of $\triangle A_1A_2A_3$, we have,
$$\measuredangle A_2OF=60^o \qquad\text{and}\qquad OA_2=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}a.$$
$$\therefore\qquad\measuredangle A_2OB_2=60^o-\theta.$$

Furthermore, we have,
$$\quad R=a+OA_2=a\left(1+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right).\tag{1}$$

We are also aware that $EB_2=b$, $OB_2=R-b$, and $A_2B_2=a+b$. Applying Pythagoras Theorem to $\triangle OEB_2$, we obtain $OE=\sqrt{R\left(R-2b\right)}$. Now, we can express $\cos\left(60^o-\theta\right)$ in terms of $R$ and $b$ as shown below.
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{b}{R-b}, \quad \cos\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{R\left(R-2b\right)}}{R-b}\quad\rightarrow\quad \cos\left(60^o-\theta\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{R\left(R-2b\right)}+\sqrt{3}b}{2\left(R-b\right)}$$

We apply the law of cosines to the $\triangle OB_2A_2$ to show that,
$$\left(a+b\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}a\right)^2+\left(R-b\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}a\right)\left(R-b\right)\cos\left(60^o-\theta\right).\tag{2}$$

After eliminating $R$ from (2) using (1), its terms having the same power of $b$ were brought together before simplifying them to obtain the following quartic equation, in which all the coefficients of the polynomial of unknown $b$ were expressed in terms of known $a$.
$$\small{\left(361+208\sqrt{3}\right)}\large{b^4}\small{-4\left(281+162\sqrt{3}\right)\large{ab^3}\small{+2\left(631+364\sqrt{3}\right)}}\large{a^2b^2}\small{-4\left(149+86\sqrt{3}\right)}\large{a^3b}\small{+\left(97+56\sqrt{3}\right)}\large{a^4}\rm{=}\small{0} \tag{3}$$

Our investigation revealed that this equation has four positive real roots, of which two are equal. It is obvious that the smallest root of (3) is equal to the radius of the required inscribed pair of twin circles. The two equal roots, which are also the largest, are the radii of the three largest inscribed circles. This means that $\left(b-a\right)^2$  is a factor of (3). Therefore, we can divide it by this factor to obtain the quadratic equation given below.
$$\left(361+208\sqrt{3}\right){\large{b^2}}-\left(402+232\sqrt{3}\right){\large{ab}}+\left(97+56\sqrt{3}\right){\large{a^2}}=0\tag{4}$$

The smaller of the two distinctive roots of (4) is,
$${\large{b}}=\dfrac{\left(201+116\sqrt{3}\right)-2\sqrt{2702+1560\sqrt{3}}}{361+208\sqrt{3}}{\large{a}},\tag{5}$$
which can be written as,
$${\large{b}}=0.35339790788718000008963432990097\times{\large{a}}.\tag{6}$$

We can eliminate $a$ from (5) and (6) using (1) to express $b$ in terms of $R$.
$${\large{b}}=\dfrac{\left(93+54\sqrt{3}\right)-2\sqrt{582+336\sqrt{3}}}{361+208\sqrt{3}}{\large{R}}\tag{7}$$
$${\large{b}}=0.16401253983674365870436092010816\times{\large{R}}$$

Since we now know $b$, we can draw two arcs, i.e. one centred at $O$ and has radius $\enspace R-b\enspace$ and the other centred at $A_2$ and has the radius $\enspace b+a,\enspace$ to intersect each other at $B_2$, which is the center of one of the two required circles.

$\bf{\underline{\text{Part 2}}}$

[image: GeometricConstruction]

The construction described below is based on inversive geometry. However, one needs not to know about inversions to carry out the steps of the construction. The circle of inversion ($\it{\Omega}$) and lengths of certain radii and line segments shown in the $\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}$ are only for those who are versed in inversions and want to closely follow the construction procedure. The aim of this construction is to locate the three points of tangency of the sought circle with the base circle, the inscribed circle, and the line $DE$.

We start the construction by drawing a line joining $O$ (center of the base circle) and $A_2$ (center of the inscribed circle). When this line is extended, it passes through $C$ (point of tangency between the base circle and the inscribed circle) and cuts the base circle again at $G$. Now, draw the tangent of the base circle at $G$ and a line perpendicular to $DE$, so that they meet at $F$. After constructing the circle $\it{\Gamma}_1$ centred at $F$, the radius of which is equal to $FC$, draw a line perpendicular to $GF$ through $F$ to intersect the circle $\it{\Gamma}_1$ at $L$. Now, we need to draw a line parallel to $GF$ through $L$. Mark the midpoint of the segment $FL$ as $K$ and draw the line $KN$ perpendicular to $FL$. Draw an arc centred at $L$ with radius $LK$ to cut the extended $FL$ at $M$. Then, draw another arc, which is centred at $F$ and has the radius $FM$, to intersect $KN$ at $B_0$. In the next step of our construction, we draw a line perpendicular to $KN$ to meet the extended lines $JL$ and $GF$ at $U_0$ and $V_0$ respectively. Join $F$ and $B_0$, so that line $FB_0$ cuts the circle $\it{\Gamma}_1$ at $W_0$.

To complete the construction, we Join $C$ to $U_0$ and denote the point of intersection between $CU_0$ and the inscribed circle as $U$, at which point the sought circle touches the inscribed circle. Similarly, when a line is drawn to join $C$ to $V_0$, that line meets the base circle at $V$, at which point the sought circle is internally tangent to the base circle. Finally, the line drawn to connect $C$ to $W_0$ intersects the line $DE$ at $W$, which marks the point of tangency between the sought circle and $DE$. Draw the circumcircle of the triangle $UVW$, which is the sought circle.

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}\space$ can be used to derive the following formula that expresses the radius $b$ of the sought circle in terms of the radius $R$ of the base circle.
$b=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{6+2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}R\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\enspace\tag{8}$
$$b\approx 0.16401253983674365870436092010815\times R$$

Although the two expressions (7) and (8) have completely different forms, they both give the exact value of $b$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R_0$ be the radius of the big circle.  Each of the three circles that are $120^\circ$ apart has a radius $R_1$, that can be obtained using

$ (R_0 - R_1) \sin \left( \dfrac{120^\circ}{2} \right) =  R_1 $

which becomes

$ R_1 ( 1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) =  \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} R_0 $

So

$R_1 = \bigg(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} }{1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\bigg) R_0 = \bigg( \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2 + \sqrt{3}} \bigg) R_0 $

The center of one of these three circles whose center makes an angle of $120^\circ$ with the $y$-axis, and is to the right of the figure is given by

$ C_1 = (R_0 - R_1) ( \sin(120^\circ) , \cos(120^\circ) ) $

Now for the red circle, let its center be $C_2 = (x, y)$ and note that its radius $R_2 = x$.

Now we can write two equations relating the distances between $C_2$ and the centers $C_0 = (0,0) $ of the big circle and the center $C_1$ of the right smaller circle.  These equations are

$ x^2 + y^2 = (R_0 - x)^2 \hspace{20pt} (1) $

$ (x - C_{1x}) ^2 + (y - C_{1y})^2 = (x + R_1)^2 \hspace{20pt} (2)$

These equations can be solved numerically, by setting $R_0 = 1$.

I did that, and obtained,

$R_2 = 0.164012539836744 R_0$

[image]